# Radiobutton checked change event not firing in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview where i have a radio button. What i need is to on the selection of the radiobutton i have to find the datakey of the gridview. Also one more issue with that is , i can select more than one radio button, which should not happen.

Comment: Have you set the autopostback property of the radiobutton to true...

Comment: Enable autopostback property of readiobutton to true.

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro, @geek - Even setting autopostback will not guarantee the results that AmRan is after.  In that case, the end user would still be able to select multiple radio control values.  In this case, this is not the ideal solution as @AmRan stated he is looking for one selection.  You will need to use a literal control to inject the radio button markup.  See the example link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a literal control to inject radio button markup.
This will handle grouping so only one radio button is selected.
You cannot do it with the standard radio control group.

See this for a complete example with working code:

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-a-gridview-column-of-radio-buttons-vb