# Confirm radio button inside gridview's event doesn't fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

In my Asp project, I have a radio button inside my gridview. The radio button only allows user to select once every time.

However when user clicks a radio button, a confirm message will appear and the record will only be saved if the user clicks "OK".

Everything is working, but now I'm facing a problem. The radio button `oncheckedchanged` seems to not fire when user clicks "OK". How can I fire the radio button event once the user clicks "Ok"?

Here is my code:
Javascript

```
function RadioCheck(rb) {
    var gv = document.getElementById('Content_PageContent_ucSubMenuItem_module_sales_customer_submenuitem_contactpersonlist_ascx_gvContactPersonList');var rbs = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < rbs.length; i++) {
        if (rbs[i].type == "radio") {
            //if radio button is check but not the selected value then false
            if (rbs[i].checked && rbs[i] != rb) {
                rbs[i].checked = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return confirm('Confirm Save?');

}
```

client-side

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Default" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbtnDefault" runat="server" onclick="RadioCheck(this);" oncheckedchanged="rdbtnDefault_CheckedChanged" Visible='<%#((string)Eval("DEFAULT")) == "Y" ? false : true %>'/>
        <asp:Image ID="imgDefault" runat="server" Height="13px" ImageUrl="~/Styles/images/tick-48x48.png"  Width="13px" Visible='<% ((string)Eval("DEFAULT")) == "Y" ? true : false %>'  />
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Server side

```
//--Register for in post back--
if (Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(DataUCContactListing) == false) {
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "gvRdBtnSelectOnce", blcGenerateScript.gvRdBtnSelectOnce(gvContactPersonList.ClientID,true), true);
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "gvSelectAllChkBox", blcGenerateScript.gvSelectAllChkBox(gvContactPersonList.ClientID), true);
}

//**Register for script**
protected void rdbtnDefault_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        RadioButton lnBTNDone = (RadioButton)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lnBTNDone.NamingContainer;
        string accountID = gvContactPersonList.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
        int contactID = int.Parse(gvContactPersonList.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString());
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
            dlcCustomerDB.updateAccountOtherDefaultN(accountID);
            dlcCustomerDB.updateAccountDefaultY(accountID, contactID);
            scope.Complete();
        }
        createGridView();
        this.Session[gbcMessageSessionID.message1] = gbcMessageAlert.saveSuccessfully;
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.Error(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is page postback when user clicks on "OK" button??

Comment: No.Seem it does not firing server side event

Comment: have you set AutoPostBack to true?

Comment: I try set autopostback to true. the server event will fire. But even when the user click cancel, the record also will save. How to detect if the user click "Ok" then the checkchange event only will be fire

Comment: See my answer below.i have added "return" keyword for onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

Look into following URLs

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/adding-a-gridview-column-of-radio-buttons-vb
[Radiobutton checked change event not firing in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971468/radiobutton-checked-change-event-not-firing-in-gridview)
Please look into this code

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rdbtnDefault" runat="server" onclick="return RadioCheck(this);" oncheckedchanged="rdbtnDefault_CheckedChanged" Visible='<%#((string)Eval("DEFAULT")) == "Y" ? false : true %>' AutoPostBack="True" />
```

I have added "return" keyword for onclick event of RadioButton.

Comment: Did you try ?I try adi. But still no able to fire server side event

Comment: Please set AutoPostBack to True

Comment: I try set Auto post back to true. No matter user click ok or cancel , it also will fire server side event. I want save record only when user click ok confirm message box